# CypressJS: Web Page Unresponsive After Authentication

Tags: javascript, authentication, azure-active-directory, integration-testing, cypress

**Goal:**
Use my Azure AD account to generate cookies that I then pass into a Cypress instance in order to hit the landing page of my site that, requires that I am fully authenticated before landing there, and be able to run my integration tests as a fully authenticated user using those cookies.

**Currently:**
This does everything that I want it to do, except that after the landing page loads in Cypress, it hangs and becomes unresponsive. Some things respond, but not everything. There is an exception getting thrown for the websites resource(s), but I have a Cypress event handler returning "false" (`() => false`) to ensure that it does not stop the Cypress integration test execution.

*Here is what I am doing:*

- Run a PuppeteerJS instance to automagically authenticate to the Azure AD credentials.

  - Generates 2 of 3 cookies.
- Do a single navigation on the landing page.

  - Generates the 3rd, and last, cookie; 3 of 3 at this point.
- Write those cookies to the `cypress.json` file.
- Launch CypressJS and run integration test (only have one test for now).
- The test loads all 3 cookies into the browser.

  - Loaded using `Cypress.env(<var>);`
  - Set cookies using `cy.setCookie(<key>, <value>, <options>)`.
- Run the test:

  - Type some text and then click the "Search" button.
  - For whatever reason the "Search" button does nothing.

This, generally, works -- except for the lack of responsiveness in the browser. I have some ideas on how to resolve this but I would like to get help and input on what someone else may or may not have done to use Azure AD authentication cookies loaded into Cypress to run authenticated integration tests.

To be clear, I authenticate to Azure AD outside of Cypress (before running it), dump the 3 cookies out to the `cypress.json` file, run the integration test (which loads up those cookies), and the tests attempt to run. Authentication is **not** happening while Cypress is running.

Comment: What I was able to determine is that if a DOM element is within a `<form>` then calling `cy.get("<element>[id=<element_id>]").click()` will not work if the DOM element within the form does not, itself, directly trigger the form submission.